# What is a great farming method for crimson charms?

Tags: runescape

In Runescape what is a great method to farm crimson charms? I need them for summoning so I can get the pack yak familiar. What monsters should I kill? What are the charm drop rates for this? I consulted the wiki to see what monsters drop them. I want a monster that drops the charms frequently and are not extremely difficult to kill with a level 161 account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Waterfiends](http://runescape.wiki/w/Waterfiend). The place I kill them at is the [Ancient Cavern](http://runescape.wiki/w/Ancient_Cavern) which you can reach from teleporting to the Barbarian Outpost with a games necklace then diving into the whirlpool, south of the Outpost.

They drop crimsons very commonly (according to the unofficial wiki, 78-79%) and they are weak to bolts.

If you're having trouble killing them, the [Vampyrism](http://runescape.wiki/w/Vampyrism) aura always helps me heal off them while attacking them.

To boost your efficiency, you can also get a [Charming imp](http://runescape.wiki/w/Charming_imp) from Daemonheim for 100,000 dungeoneering tokens. What this does is automatically puts charms into your inventory from a drop. Or if this is not a viable option, you can do the Distraction and Diversion [Familiarisation](http://runescape.wiki/w/Familiarisation), which can triple your charm drops for 40 minutes.

They also give great  combat experience :)